# Electronic Data Interchange (EDI) is JSON in this time?

Tags: json, edi

There is a lot of talk about EDI in companies, but as it is used in 2017

Comment: There's no question here.  Is this trying to get to the bottom of "Is EDI dead and replaced by JSON?".

Comment: json is nice as a import/exportt format in edi. API's like json. Json is still relativly simple ,like xml once was. At a certain time Electronic Data Interchange (EDI) was XML in that time ;-))

Answer (score 0):

[EDI software](https://xedi.com/blog/what-is-edi-software/) is still very much used in companies.  It's been around for decades and is finely ingrained in the central infrastructure of all major retailers, manufacturers, and distributors.  That's not to say JSON driven APIs don't have their place.  The link between the two is in AS4, however, AS2 still dominates as the preferred web based transmission standard.

Answer (score 0):

EDI has a lot of well established formats like EDIFACT, X.12, etc. So companies setting up EDI for the exchange of documents for orders, invoices and other standard stuff JSON is of no use, you will most of the time end up with one of the standard formats already out there for decades.

But you still see JSON in situations where a couple of years before you were using XML and WebServices. People who don't like WebServices due to its complexity tend to use RESTful services instead and therefore exchange JSON data. But these aren't EDI rather than EAI (enterprise application integration) projects.